# Java: Save an image in one specific directory

Tags: java, image-uploading

i found on the web this servlet java that uploads an image from a xmlHttpRequest of level 2.
now, in the servlet i have the image object with all the characteristics that i need: name, size, dimensions, ecc...
Now I want to store the image in a directory in the server. How can i do?

the code of the servlet is the following (not mine):

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String ajaxUpdateResult = "";

    try {

        List<FileItem> items = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);            
        for (FileItem item : items) {
            if (item.isFormField()) {
                ajaxUpdateResult += "Field " + item.getFieldName() + 
                " with value: " + item.getString() + " is successfully read\n\r";
            } else {
                String fileName = item.getName();
                InputStream content = item.getInputStream();
                response.setContentType("text/plain");
                response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

                // Do whatever with the content InputStream.

                System.out.println(item.getSize());

                //System.out.println(Streams.asString(content));
                ajaxUpdateResult += "File " + fileName + " is successfully uploaded\n\r";
            }
        }
    } catch (FileUploadException e) {
        throw new ServletException("Parsing file upload failed.", e);
    }
    response.getWriter().print(ajaxUpdateResult);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply try this....

```
try {
    // retrieve image
    BufferedImage bi = getMyImage();
    File outputfile = new File("saved.png");
    ImageIO.write(bi, "png", outputfile);
} catch (IOException e) {
    ...
}
```

**See this link:**

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-an-image-to-file-imageio/

**/////////////////////// Edited Part/////////////////////**

**Two ways to do it**

**1.** Using `HTTP-POST` with `multiparted` file, it needs `Apaches commons` library

```
public String postDataCreation(final String url, final String xmlQuery,final String path){

        final StringBuilder sa  = new StringBuilder();

        final File file1 = new File(path);




        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable(){


            public void run() {

                try
                {
                     HttpClient client = MySSLSocketFactory.getNewHttpClient();
                     HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
                     FileBody bin1 = new FileBody(file1);

                     MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();

                     reqEntity.addPart("dish_photo", bin1);

                     reqEntity.addPart("xml", new StringBody(xmlQuery));

                     post.setEntity(reqEntity);

                     HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

                     HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                        InputStream i = entity.getContent();

                        Log.d("Vivek", i.toString());
                        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(i);

                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

                        String s = null;


                        while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {

                            Log.d("YumZing", s);
                            sa.append(s);
                        }






                }
                catch (Exception ex){

                }

            }





        });

        t2.start();

        try {
            t2.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Getting from Post Data Method "+sa.toString());
        return sa.toString();
    }
```

**2.** Use `FTP` to upload it, use the `Apaches commons` library

```
    public void goforIt(){


            FTPClient con = null;

            try
            {
                con = new FTPClient();
                con.connect("xx.xx.xx.xx");

                if (con.login("Administrator", "361wl-sin"))
                {
                    con.enterLocalPassiveMode(); // important!
                    con.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                    String data = "/sdcard/prerakm4a.m4a";
                    //ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(data.getBytes());
                    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(data));
                    boolean result = con.storeFile("/prerakm4a.m4a", in);
                    in.close();
                    if (result) System.out.println("upload result"+" succeeded");
                    con.logout();
                    con.disconnect();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
  }
```

Comment: which method is getMyImage()?

Comment: @user1695091, its simply a custom method to get the image... try the link i have given, you will find the small example to do it...

Comment: @user1695091, Ok.. i think you want to upload the image on the server... ok try my edited code.......

Comment: @Please refresh the code, to update the correction in the post

Comment: In order to use Apaches commons library what do I have to do? from this link what do I have to download? http://commons.apache.org/downloads/index.html

Comment: I found it! I downloaded the net and not more errors!
I still have some questions for you though, I'm just a beginner sorry! I thank you for your patience ... I hope I can make this work with your help!

Comment: 1) con.connect("xx.xx.xx.xx"); where do I find the right address? and credentials for login? 2) String data = "/sdcard/prerakm4a.m4a"; with this statement sets the destination folder of images? 3) Log.v("upload result", "succeeded"); what is this? thanks

Comment: `xx.xx.xx.xx` - will be IP address of the Server you want to upload to, you should have the Login credentials.  `String data = "/sdcard/prerakm4a.m4a";` - is the music file on my disk that i want to upload. (In your case it will be the image)... And **ignore** the `Log.v()` as thats for android, instead use System.out.println()

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
// retrieve image
BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(content);
File outputfile = new File(fileName);
ImageIO.write(bi, "png", outputfile);
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: it works...but how can i put the image in the server? The code doesn't show errors but i can't see the image in the folders of the project...

Comment: You need to save it in some folder in the disk drive. Try something like "C:/images/"+filename in the File method.

Comment: but in the future images has to be saved in remote, not locally...if i put them in C:// remain in my pc...or not?

Comment: You can map a new drive in your pc with a remote machine. Computer -> Map network drive -> Select letter and destination